# Second time ajax call not working

Tags: html, ajax, highcharts

This is my page code and when I click on button work just first time:

I saw question about but I couldn't solve my problem!

```
  <html>
            <head>
            <title>tsee</title>
    <script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $("#btn").click(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    URL: "../../generate", //this read from a servlet
                    type: "get",

                    data:{
                        id:120
                    },

                    cache: false,
                    complete: function () { alert('farshid') },
                    success: function (data) {
                        $('#result').html(data);
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        alert('Error')
                    }


                })

            })
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="button" id="btn" value="Ajax Request" />
    <div id="result">

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

When I click on button, my result load to div(Draw a chart in this div and Because avoid from huge code I avoid to write here) and in second time when I click on don't work.

How can I solve this problem?
And this is video for better understanding problem.([video from my run enviroment](http://uplod.ir/3v7k2ihsw2a6/12-31-2014_5-30-44_AM.mp4.htm)

Comment: Your whole page html is reload again over this div <div id="result"> </div>. So, your button with is also created again with the same id. And your click is woking on first button id. Also try this $("#btn").on('click',function () {});

Comment: Seems to work: http://jsfiddle.net/90vgxqh4/2/

Comment: Please check that after load the abc.html file first time. Then the js which is also loaded with this abc.html page which is conflict with the existing page. That's way may it's not working second time.

Comment: @lakhan, how do you know the ajax loads the same page ? And besides that the results go in the `#result` div so the outer button is not affected..

Comment: You say that you hide some code (*for the chart drawing*) but perhaps that is where the problem lies.. So i would suggest you post that code as well (*either here or at pastebin / jsfiddle / etc*)

Comment: This is my jsp page code where call ajax and js codes http://jsfiddle.net/xrb9nyup/2/

Comment: I cannot spot any serious errors on the code you posted (*you do have an extra  tralling comma `,` in the **Browser share** data*). There is also no need to use `$(function(){});` inside the `success` method (*you are binding the code to run on the `document.ready` event, but since the initial `.ready` has already run, it will just execute the code immediately*).

Comment: I dont know if this will solve the problem, but I think its generally good practice to preventDefault() on your click event. Try adding: $("#btn").on("click", function(ev){ ev.preventDefault(); //your ajax code here; }); It wouldn't hurt, and it might help :]

Comment: This too has not worked

Comment: @farshid, the problem has nothing to do with the click button. It has to do with the code you use to initialize the HighChart plugin. I have posted an answer explaining it, so have a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at your video and the jsfiddle, the problem has nothing to do with the button.

If you had opened the console, you would have seen that the problem occurs when setting the options for the HighCharts plugin.

You try to change the colors from flat to gradients, but you run this code each time you try to draw a chart.

This code assumes that the initial colors are hex values but the second time you run it it is not hex (*since you changed them on the first run*), and this causes the plugin to crash and stop executing (*and thus it never reaches the part that draws the chart*)

See problematic demo: http://jsfiddle.net/dgr2ky4h/

---

You need to remove the HighChart color setting from that function and only run it once when you load the page.

See working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/dgr2ky4h/1/

So remove the following code from your success method

```
Highcharts.getOptions().colors = Highcharts.map(
    Highcharts.getOptions().colors,

    function (color) {
        console.log(color);
        return {
            radialGradient: {
                cx: 0.5,
                cy: 0.3,
                r: 0.7
            },
            stops: [
                [0, color],
                [
                1,
                Highcharts.Color(color)
                    .brighten(-0.3)
                    .get('rgb')] // darken
                ]
        };
```

and run it out of the success only once..

```
<script>
    $(function(){
    Highcharts.getOptions().colors = Highcharts.map(
        Highcharts.getOptions().colors,

            function (color) {
                console.log(color);
                return {
                    radialGradient: {
                        cx: 0.5,
                        cy: 0.3,
                        r: 0.7
                    },
                    stops: [
                        [0, color],
                        [1, Highcharts.Color(color)
                            .brighten(-0.3)
                            .get('rgb')] // darken
                        ]
                };    
          });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I add this section("and run it out of the success only once..") to $(ducument).ready(function(){//I paste your aforementioned here and now it work}); //function thanU(){ alert('thanku');}

Answer (score 1):

I think you can try .on('click', function(){ // your code }) instead of simple .click function.

Comment: Can you try calling the function inside window.onload function instead of document.ready()

Comment: @jango why? what difference would that make ?

Comment: Window.onload is called only after all the elements is loaded into the dom. ready() function is called when the page loads.

Comment: @jango the html is already available when the dom ready is called, for binding events to it.  Load waits for external resources like images etc. It will make no difference here since the button is already available in the html.

Answer (score -1):

could be a binding issue...
.click binds event to button as many times as you click. try
Either using $("element").on("click", function(){do stuff here});

or unbind click on button after you execute stuff...

wrong answer...Apologies

Comment: no it doesn't. Please read the docs about the `.click()` before posting wrong answers